# Conditional Transform in VSCode Snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Here is a vscode snippet i am using to replace first colon of each line with double colon.

```
"Description List": {
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+:)(.+)$/$1:$2/gm}"
    ],
    "description": "Description List"
},
```

The issue is, if there is no `:` at any line then a `:` is placed at the beginning of it anyways.

For example, if the input is:

```
Point One: This is first line
Point Two: This is second line
This is third line
```

Then the output becomes:

```
Point One:: This is first line
Point Two:: This is second line
:This is third line
```

Then expected output is:

```
Point One:: This is first line
Point Two:: This is second line
This is third line
```

I have tried, `${1:+$1:}` but it prints `$1:`.

How to say that if there is no colon then print the line as it is without any transformation.

Comment: I don't get a `:` printed out when there is no `:` in the selected text.  Please show an example of the text you are using and perhaps a gif of it happening.

Comment: @Mark added sample input and output.

Comment: Does this help: `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+)(:)(.+)$/$1$2${2:+:}$3/gm}"`?  And are you selecting all the lines in one selection?  Are you triggering the snippet via  a keybinding?  I still can't reproduce the output you are getting.

Comment: Thanks. The one you gave works.  `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+:)(.+)$/$1${1:+:}$2/gm}"` also works.

Comment: `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+)(:)(.+)$/$1${2:+::}$3/gm}"` also works.

Comment: `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.*?:)/$1:/gm}"` also works.

Comment: I'll add an answer with my original suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+p",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    // "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+:)(.+)$/$1:$2/gm}"  // your original version

    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.+)(:)(.+)$/$1$2${2:+:}$3/gm}"
  }
},
```

My versi9on treats the `:` as its own capture group.  And then adds an additional `:` if that group exists with this:

```
$2${2:+:}   // reinsert the original :, add another : if there is a capture group 2
```

[I still am having trouble reproducing your issue, but this form of the snippet transform should be a little "safer" because it really focuses on the presence of the `:` as its own capture group.]